# how to prevent clicking on a disabled button through the parent component in angular?

Tags: angular, button, components, disabled-input

I have a generic component `app-button` which contains a button element.

Button component html

```
<button [type]="type" [disabled]="isLoading || !!disabled">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Button component ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: 'views/button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['styles/button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() class: string;
  isLoading: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.type = "submit";
  }
}
```

I added (click) to my component and it works fine. But when I put `disabled` attribute it disables the button, but the (click) still works when you click on a content.

```
<app-button (click)="signIn()" [disabled]="true">
    <span>Signin</span>
</app-button>
```

Comment: Well you can't *disable* a component

Comment: In your `signIn` function you check the event target's properties for disabled...or just don't attach a click event handler if you know it's going to be disabled

Comment: If you want to stick with this logic , i guess you could bind the click on the `<button>` tag itself and pass the function as an attribute of your component.

Comment: but is there any way to make it generic for all buttons? I have a lot of uses already :)

Comment: @Gbac do you mean something like this [click]="func", then in compoenent @Input() func: any; 
if(!disabled) { func(); }

Comment: Yeah something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think that your problem is that you are 
disabling you **child** component and you have the **click** event in the parent component

A solution could be moving your `(click)="signIn()"` to your child component and it will be disable and add an `@Output` decorator to receive the `callback` from the child

**Child Component html**

```
<button [type]="type" [disabled]="isLoading || !!disabled" (click)="signIn()">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

**Child Component ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: 'views/button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['styles/button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() class: string;
  @Output() callback = new EventEmitter();
  isLoading: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.type = "submit";
  }

  signIn(){
     this.callback.emit();
  }

}
```

**Parent Component html**

```
<app-button (callback)="signIn()" [disabled]="true">
    <span>Signin</span>
</app-button>
```

[Demo StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2g6dm)